# Should I throw Exceptions in own Database class with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

Hey I have Database class with PDO and some other classes for an object oriented forum:

```
class Database {

    private $databaseConnection;

    function __construct($path = "", $dbUsername = "", $dbPassword = ""){
        $parts = explode('.',$path);
        $documentType = array_pop($parts);

        if(($path == "") || ((strcmp($documentType, "sq3") !== 0) && (strcmp($documentType, "sqlite") !== 0))) {
            throw new Exception("The Database must bee .sq3 or .sqlite and Path must be stated");
        }

        $this->databaseConnection = new PDO('sqlite:' . $path, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
        $this->databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        self::query('CREATE TABLE...)');
    }

    function query($sql, $params = NULL){
    ...
    }

    function getObjects($objectTable, $searchedForAttribute, $attributeValue){
    ...
    }


    function insertObject($object){
    ...
    }

    function updateObject($object){
    ...
    }

    function removeObject($object){
    ...
    }

    ...//some other methods

    function __destruct(){
        unset($this->databaseConnection);
    }
}
```

Should I use Exceptions ? Such like:

```
    function insertObject($object){
    try {
       ...
    }catch(PDOException $e){
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
         }
    }
```

As a result I have to catch this Exceptions somewhere else and give it out in a different way. For Example: I have a Class User and a table User. So if a new registration is filled out I have to validate the information for the new User. So if an expactant User choose a name which is already in the Database I would throw an Exception although I only need a message for the User which says that the name is already assigned.

So I thought it would be better if I do something like:

```
    function insertObject($object){
    try {
       ...
    }catch(PDOException $e){
            return "Username already assigned";
         }
    }
```

Of course I do not always know why an Exception gets thrown but in such a case I would validate datas with an if-block.

So how should I use Exception handling in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is simple, and yet quite vast all at the same time (IMHO).

Firstly I'd recommend you grab something like Doctrine or another good off-the-shelf ORM package if you want a "simple database abstraction through ORM/models".  Or a framework.

If (like me) you're a real sucker for doing things from scratch like this, then I've a few suggestions from painful prior experiences.

1. Returning strings (like you suggest at the end of your question) is a Really Bad Idea(TM).  Strings are good for stringy things - not defined responses from one piece of code to another like this.  Defined constants (using, let's say, integer values) is better for this route - IMHO.
2. Exceptions make a lot of sense here - you wish to say "I failed to do what you asked of me, I need you to handle it".

If you choose to go down the exception route (I'm pro both - coming from a C/C++ background originally) use string values for the stringy bits (give the exception a human-friendly message to display) and also give it a machine-friendly attribute too (for the code which will capture it).

`\PDOException` makes natural sense to state that a *database failure* just occurred, like "I lost connectivity" or "MySQL borked".  You might wish to just let those exceptions raise themselves back to the code calling yours...

For your model-specific errors, I'd create appropriate exception classes.  Literally:

```
class UserModelException extends \Exception {
 ... // Optional stuff here
}
```

Then you can catch different *sorts* of errors in the calling code:

```
try {
 ...
} catch (\UserModelException $e) {
 ...
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
 ...
}
```

Etc.

Of course you might want to catch the PDO exceptions in your model to determine if something like a unique key constraint just blew up - i.e. indicating that the username already exists.  In this situation you might (in your model) want to:

```
try {
 ...
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
   if (...) { // unique constraint error - username already taken
      throw new \UserModelException(...);
   } else {
      throw $e;
   }
}
```

Does that in any way make sense, and is it in any way helpful?

I can't think (off the top of my head) a situation that I'd recommend throwing a literal `\Exception` object - I'd always inherit it on a per-context basis.

Comment: Yes now I have an idea how to use and handle Exceptions. Thanks a lot also for the clarifying second answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use Exceptions

Definitely yes. That's the only way.

> Such like:

```
}catch(PDOException $e){
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
     }
```

There is absolutely no point in doing such a re-throw. Why don't you just leave PDOException alone?

> Should I throw Exceptions in own Database class with PDO?

Yes, you should.

> So how should I use Exception handling in this case?

You have to understand two things first.

1. Exceptions are **different**. That's on purpose. Yes, you could use exceptions for both runtime errors and user validation. But that would be **different exceptions** with completely **different handling**.
2. No database handling class should ever validate user data. That's different classes.

For the runtime exceptions (like query failed) there is not much handling needed. Write a common exception handler that is doing some common job of logging the message and showing page of excuses. Of course NO REAL ERROR MESSAGE SHOULD BE SHOWN to user. Just a common excuse.

But for the user validation use try..catch to see if all the data were validated all right, by means of catching **your own UserValidationException**.

In other words, there are Exceptions for the programmer and Exceptions for the user. You have to treat them differently. A "The Database must bee .sq3 or .sqlite and Path must be stated" os one for the programmer and shouldn't be shown to the user. Instead, it have to be logged for the programmer's reference, an excuses page have to be shown to the user and program have to be halted.

A "Username already taken" is one for the user and have to be shown to them.

To distinguish these two types of exceptiions, different Exception classes have to be used.

The only case where these two types can possibly meet is a certain errors from database that can be used for the validation purpose. In this case a conditional block have to be implemented, as it shown in the other answer.

However, exceptions could be inconvenient for validating user input, as you probably want to gather all possible errors, not one. In this case do not use exceptions for data validation fut instead run your validations one by one and add errors to an array.